# How to refer to empty cell in pandas transformation

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to write code that will create a new excel document with a new column that has different values depending on the existing data. Specifically, if a cell under "Servicer" is empty, I would like a new column named "Needs Cleanup?" to say "Yes" in that row, and otherwise say "No". I would expect the following code to work, but it returns "No" for every row, even if the "Servicer" cell is empty. I have also tried using the python value `None` in place of `''` with the same results.

```
filepath = 'C:/Users/jackley/Desktop/'

filename = 'test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(filepath+filename)

df["Needs Cleanup?"]=df["Servicer"].apply(lambda x: "Yes" if x == '' else "No")

df.to_excel(filepath+"test"+filename,index=False)
```

I have used this code structure to create conditional values for a new column without problem, as long as my if/else statements were referring to values that did actually show up in the "Servicer" column. It is just when I try to create a conditional statement based on whether a cell is empty that I am having this problem. Is there a way within this code structure to return different values based on whether an indicated cell is empty?

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Are your fill values `np.nan`?

Comment: can you print `df["Servicer"].unique()`. Perhaps the empty values are not the empty string. Could be `' '` a single space or something

Comment: thank you @aALollz, this was a good idea, python is telling me that the empty values are in fact "NaN", but for some reason that is beyond me, even when i change the code to `"Yes" if x == "NaN" else "No"` it is still only giving me a long list of "No"s :(

Comment: thank you @rahlf23 - this was a good idea, and suggested as an answer below, but unfortunately importing numpy and using the np.nan value to try to identify empty cells is still not working in this code.

Comment: Just to be thorough, you did `import numpy as np` correct?

Comment: @rahlf23 thank you for checking -  yes i did (admittedly not on my first try though!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand why the suggested answers are not working, but I was able to solve my problem by adding the following code:

`df.fillna(" ",inplace=True)`

and then changing my conditional statement to read:

`"Yes" if x == " " else "No"`

(thanks to "Code Like a Girl" for having this answer in an old blog post!)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You need to replace '' to np.nan.

```
df["Needs Cleanup?"]=df["Servicer"].apply(lambda x: "Yes" if x == np.nan else "No")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response Parth. Unfortunately importing numpy and using the expression you suggest does not change the results and the "Needs Cleanup?" column remains full of "No"s. I'm stumped!